# Navigation Bar on TVC from storyboard not appearing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I dragged out a TVC from storyboard and put a table view as a subview of a main view, but when I run the app the navigation bar doesn't show? What am I doing wrong?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a navigation controller added in your storyboard and connect it with TableView Controller . 
UINavigation Controller works as a Stack on ViewControllers.

[image: Your Storyboard should look like this]

Check here for a tutorial :
[Navigation controller Tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/)

Integrating with storyboard : [Storyboard tutorial with Tableview and Navigation Controller](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Then do this :

In the interface buildr select your tableview Controller and check the left hand side tick on enable navigation controller .

And , put this in viewDidLoad

self.navigationController.hidden  = NO;

Comment: I don't see that option in storyboard?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/ 

refer this link to use Navigation controller with Storyboard

Comment: Well, the navigation bar was working fine when I used a TVC from storyboard and let the default tableView exist by itself. I need to add something below the TableView so I created another View and added the TableView as a subview, as you can see from my screen shot. This made the navigation bar go away...

Comment: Ok. This is gonna be a lil complicated for you but try using a UIviewController rather than UITableviewController and add you views and tableviews on top of that

Comment: self.navigationController.hidden = NO;
 you did this .. in your viewDidLoad?

Comment: NM i finally got it working. I had to drag out a Navigation Bar out instead of using Top Bar drop down from the inspector. Wierd?